# LaTeX Glossaries remove unwanted blue text

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to use **glossaries** package and it is working fine. But there are some strange "blue" text right before each acronyms. Please have a look at the picture to have a better understanding.

[image: LaTex Glossaries Package Issue]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}
\newacronym{ann}{ANN}{Artificial Neural Network}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\begin{document}

\section{Support Vector Machine}
\label{sec:svm}

\gls{svm} is one of the most popular Supervised Learning algorithms, which is used for Classification as well as Regression problems. However, primarily, it is used for Classification problems in Machine Learning.

The goal of the \gls{svm} algorithm is to create the best line or decision boundary that can segregate n-dimensional space into classes so that we can easily put the new data point in the correct category in the future. This best decision boundary is called a hyperplane.

\end{document}
```

Finally when I had to use the acronyms, I used `\gls{svm}`. That's all I followed. But I don't know why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update: When I use `pdfLaTeX` as my compiler, the `blue` text is gone. But when I use `LaTeX` as my compiler then the `blue` text appears. But as I am using `psfrag` package for some of my graphics files, I have to use `LaTeX` as my compiler. So what can I do in this case?**

Comment: show a small but complete example and not only snippets. That make it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Please have a look now. Sorry, for privacy concern, I can't show the exact content. But I have made a replica of it maintaining the code structure, just replacing the contents. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Please have a look now. Sorry, for privacy concern, I can't show the exact content. But I have made a replica of it maintaining the code structure, just replacing the contents. @Mensch

Comment: you shouldn't load local files like your graphic in such an example. And you should *test* your example. This here errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, I got your point. But if you don't mind, can you please use any sample vector file instead of my shown file? I think then you can compile the code

Comment: No then I still can't compile the code. Try it out. Also try if you really need the figure to demonstrate your problem (I doubt it, it has nothing to do with acronyms.). Do not guess what could be needed to show your problem or not, check it before posting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry for your trouble. Would you please check the new code now. It is compiling here in my overleaf account. It should work now on your side. Also I have remove the figure part.

Comment: when I compile that on overleaf with latex + texlive 2021, overleaf reports 8 errors. see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D4TI.png

Comment: I get `! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry \`svm' has not been defined.`  it doesn't appear to use the acronyms.tex file you suggest and why include packages such as float and booktabs here, that just makes it harder to debug.

Comment: If I try the added example   with latex/makeglossaries/latex/dvips/ps2pdf, I get no blue text and no errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes. Just writing `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` after the `\begin{document}`, the `blue` text is gone. Thanks!! You should add this as an answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: I don't see how you got any output at all printing the glossary before begin document (I did not) the aux file is not open at that point. You may have been picking up some old glossary from a previous version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah it might be. my bad. however thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ignored the overleaf errors. It reported 8 errors from your example (before it was edited and corrected) and the first one was the most important:

[image]

You were trying to print the glossary in the preamble, and this doesn't work.  Moving the `\printglossary` into the document avoid this errors and also repairs your output.

Never ignore such errors. The output is random after such an error!

Comment: Thank you for tolerating my craziness and being with me till solving it :)